# how to remove custom eclipse project and all its references externally

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-kepler

I am using Eclipse Kepler on Ubuntu 14.04.

I was trying to import Openjdk8 project following 
https://java.net/projects/adoptopenjdk/pages/EclipseProjectsForOpenJDK

and in the process was trying to create **swing** project. But kepler stopped unexpectedly while creating **a new java project from existing ant build file.**

When I re-started Kepler, it refused to start. I checked in .log file for some error and found

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-05-18 11:27:24.097
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: Not implemented [multiple displays]
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4423)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.checkDisplay(Display.java:767)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.create(Display.java:908)...
```

Since error occurred while creating **swing** project, I decided to remove it manually by renaming it at.

- current Workspace.
- .metadata/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects

When I re-started Kepler. I was getting error related to project **swing**.

```
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.core.resources 4 567 2014-05-18 11:27:23.553
!MESSAGE Could not read metadata for 'swing'.
!STACK 1
 org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException(~/.../.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/swing/1.tree)[568]: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ~/.../.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/swing/1.tree (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)


!MESSAGE Could not write metadata for '/swing'.
!STACK 0
java.io.FileNotFoundException:     
~/.../.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/swing/1.tree (No such file or directory)
...

Contains: The project description file (.project) for 'swing' is missing.  This file   contains important information about the project.  The project will not function properly   until this file is restored.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.resources 4 271 2014-05-18 11:27:24.608
!MESSAGE Errors occurred while refreshing resources with the local file system.
```

I have already created a new Workspace as suggested in other posts and it is working fine.

But I am curious to know where else my project references are stored and how can I remove them manually to work on existing Workspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any plugin can save data about the workspace in the `.metadata` directory so it is not really possible to have a definitive list of where references are stored.

One place references are stored is in the `nnnn.tree` file in the `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.root` directory. This is a binary file containing a list of all the projects, folders and files in the workspace. It is not really possible to alter this file by hand. Restarting Eclipse with the `-clean` option does seem to rebuild this file.

Comment: After spending hours banging my head and shuffling files under .metadata, I finally got the solution that worked for me.

1. Stop Eclipse.
2. Rename project_name in your workspace.
3. Rename project_name in {$workspace}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/
4. Rename file .snap in {$workspace}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/
5. Start Eclipse.

In my case project_name was <b>swing</b>.
 
If it works, renamed folders can be safely removed.

Comment: I did see my other projects listed in nnn.tree (181.tree in my case) except for the project I was trying to find.